# createNativeStackNavigator is not a function when running Jest test

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-navigation

I am adding a Jest unit test for my hook `useActiveInspectionProvider.test.tsx` which is based on a Context/Provider wrapper.  However, the react-navigation steps for setup appear to be a blocker for me as it's failing repeatedly, no matter my attempt to `jest.mock` any of the react-navigation librs.

My goal is to verify state is changed on the state of the provider, after 3 API clicks.  I have my mock data ready to go.  I am mocking APIs successfully in an alternate Provider test.  However the successful test has no relationship with `useRoute` or `useNavigation`

I also am not feeling good about re-writing the actual code in a style that makes it possible to write the test, such as making a wrapper and injecting routes as props.  That's what the `useRoute` hook is for, after all!

here is the test I have started to write:

```
describe('useActiveInspectionProvider', () => {
  test('#handleNextPress sends expected payload', async () => {

// one variation of the Wrapper
    const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
      console.log({ children });

      return (
        <AuthWrapper user={mockUser} userToken="user-token">
          <VehicleDataProvider>
            <InspectionsDataProvider>
              <ActiveInspectionProvider>{children}</ActiveInspectionProvider>
            </InspectionsDataProvider>
          </VehicleDataProvider>
        </AuthWrapper>
      );
    };

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useActiveInspectionContext(), {
      wrapper,
    });

    act(() => {
      if (!InspectionData.formGroups[1].formFields[0].formFieldOptions) {
        throw new Error('Missing FormField options data');
      }
      console.log(result.current); // is undefined


      // test action from Provider
      result.current.handleNextPress({
        [InspectionData.formGroups[1].formFields[0].uuid]:
          InspectionData.formGroups[1].formFields[0].formFieldOptions[1].value,
      });
    });

// never gets this far

    await waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(fetch as jest.Mock).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(');
  });
```

Since I have need to set a route state, I have tried mocking such as:

```
jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
      return {
        ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native'),
        useNavigation: jest.fn(() => ({})),
        useRoute: () => ({
          params: {
            aggId: '',
            section: '0eafdffc-8ba5-45b6-ada8-9372dabe81c2',
            step: '1e46bdf9-a30a-4d41-bc61-a39b0a86d2f3',
            name: 'Dev 1',
            vehicleId: '26284',
          },
        }),
      };
    });
```

This doesn't seem to have any impact.

I am getting an error from my Stack Navigation instance:

> TypeError: (0 , _nativeStack.createNativeStackNavigator) is not a function
> [image]

I have created a repo to show replication, which includes the `jest-setup`, 'jest-config'` and other important parts which shows 3 passing & 1 failing test.

There are so many layers of Providers in our app. I am trying to setup only what is needed to test my actual hook/provider, not the functionality of anything else, such as logging in or user location.

Repo: https://github.com/lucksp/expo-rne-jest-test

There is [another test `Wrapper` component](https://github.com/lucksp/expo-rne-jest-test/blob/main/src/test-utils/wrapper.tsx#L9), which is a copy of almost the whole Provider layer.

Thank you for your suggestions in getting this test to run.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what happens if within your `jest.mock` you add a mock for the `createNativeStackNavigator`? I have worked with `jest.mock` in the past as well and it can show some weird behaviour sometimes.

Comment: Another thing I could suspect is a sub dependency of the `@react-navigation/native` being mocked as well, do you also mock `@react-navigation/native-stack`?

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: the mock of `@react-navigation/native-stack` at least makes the original error go away.

Now, just need to understand why my providers aren't functioning